# How can I display string values to multiple labels in a custom collectionView Cell in swift ios?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

```
var leadername = ["1","2","3","4"]

var districts = ["Delhi","Kerala"]



override func viewDidLoad() {



    leadTableSetup()
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func leadTableSetup(){

    LeadTableView.delegate = self
    LeadTableView.dataSource = self

    self.LeadTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "LeaderBoardTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "leadCell")


}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 5

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 14

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "leadCell") as! LeaderBoardTableViewCell
    // Set text from the data model
    cell.areaLbl.text = districts[indexPath.row]
    cell.leaderNameLbl.text = leadername[indexPath.row]



    return cell

}
```

I need to display "leadername" and "districts" string value to label in custom view cell.How can I achieve this? I need to display it to the labels which I have declared in custom Collection view cell

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to have a *static* `UITableView`. [This article may help](https://www.appcoda.com/ios-static-table-view-storyboard/) (it's old, but still relevant). Basically, you set the content of the cells in the storyboard if they do not need to be changed while the app is running. You current code does, however, seem to be fine. Please provide more information about the problem if this is not what you're looking for.

Comment: I have declared two strings and I want to declare one string to one label and the second string to the other label in the custom collection view cell. I am using xib by the way.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "leadCell") as! LeaderBoardTableViewCell
    // Set text from the data model
    cell.leaderNameLbl.text = leadername[indexPath.row] + districts[indexPath.row % 2]    


    return cell

}
```